# console.log(this) causes app to freeze

Tags: react-native, constructor, console.log

I have the following class.  It appears I can console.log(this) in the constructor but if I try to console.log(this) anyplace else the app won't start.  Could someone explain what's going on?  For instance, in componentDidMount I can console.log(this.interval) but not console.log(this)

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(){

    super()
    this.state={
      count:0,
  }
  console.log(this)
}

componentDidMount(){
   this.interval=setInterval(this.inc,1000)

}
componentWillUnmount(){
  clearInterval(this.interval)
}

inc=()=>{
  console.log(this)

  this.setState(prevState =>({
    count: prevState.count + 1,
  }))
}

  render() {
  
    return (
       <View>
         <Count count={this.state.count}></Count>
       </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey, can you please also paste the code that doesn't work?

Also there is a commented out console.log statement within `#inc` that has a type, which is most likely going to throw a redScreen when run.

Comment: ok, if you now run the app freezes because of the console.log in the inc method